# Is Python list variable not passing by reference?

Tags: python, list

I'm confused with the pass-by-ref and pass-by-value in Python.
In the following code, when `listB = listA`, listB should being assigned the pointer (reference) to the list in ListA variable. Any changes to listB should be reflected on listA. However, that is not the case in my test. Am I doing something wrong with the code? I'm running Python 3.4.3

```
>>> listA = [1,2,3]
>>> listB = listA
>>> listA = [4,5,6]
>>> print(listA, listB)
[4, 5, 6] [1, 2, 3]
>>> listB[0] ='new'
>>> print(listA, listB)
[4, 5, 6] ['new', 2, 3]
```

Comment: you are re-assigning `listA`, so it is no longer pointing at the same value as `listB`

Comment: There are good articles on Python's execution model. https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `listA = [4,5,6]`, the reference to `listA` (that was assigned to `listB`) no longer points to `listA`, since you completely replaced `listA` with a new list.

If you remove that line, you will find that it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning `listA` altogether, so there is no relation between it and `listB`.

For example:

```
listA = [2,2,3]

listB = listA

id(listA)
Out[6]: 90404936

id(listB)
Out[7]: 90404936

listA[0]=2

id(listA)
Out[9]: 90404936

listB
Out[10]: [2, 2, 3]
```

But then when you reassign `listA` you lose that `id`:

```
listA = [3,3,3]

id(listA)
Out[12]: 92762056
```

But `listB` stays at the same id:

```
id(listB)
Out[13]: 90404936
```

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I'm confused with the pass-by-ref and pass-by-value in python.

Actually Python does not use **either** call-by-value **or** call-by-reference: it uses [call-by-object-sharing](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm). This is basically like call-by-value, except that the "value" in question is actually the reference to the object that holds the actual value.

Fundamentally, the way to think about variables in Python is that they are actually [names that can refer to other objects](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), not values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, think of a namespace as being implemented by a 2-column table listing names and addresses. Also, note that the assignment operator `=` causes the right side to be evaluated, represented in memory if not already represented, and *then* causes the variable on the left side of the assignment to be bound in the symbol table to the address of the representation. Working through your code one line at a time:

```
listA = [2, 3, 4]
```

causes 2, 3, and 4 to be represented in memory at particular addresses. Then the brackets cause a list object to be represented in memory, with an address for the class, an int for its length, and an array of addresses for its elements. Finally, the name `listA` is placed in the namespace table and bound to the address for that list object.

```
listB = listA
```

A second entry `listB` is made in the namespace table and bound to the same address for the list.

```
listA = [4, 5, 6]
```

creates representations of three ints and a list in memory and changes the address referenced by listA in the namespace table, binding it to the new list.

```
listB[0] = 'new'
```

causes the string 'new' to be represented in memory and then changes the list object bound to `listB` so that that list's first element now refers to the address of the string.

If `listA` hadn't been reassigned to a new object, it would still point to the same list and you would see the same change in the list's first element whether using the `listA` or `listB` token.